# Align lists on showing or hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list

I have a list where every item has a sublist. To style them i have used CSS.

```
<ul class="left">
    <li class="itemc">Item 1
        <ul class="subitem">
            <li>Subitem1</li>
            <li>Subitem2</li>
            <li>Subitem3</li>
            <li>Subitem4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="itemc">Item 2
        <ul class="subitem">
            <li>Subitem1</li>
            <li>Subitem2</li>
            <li>Subitem3</li>
            <li>Subitem4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="itemc">Item 3
        <ul class="subitem">
            <li>Subitem1</li>
            <li>Subitem2</li>
            <li>Subitem3</li>
            <li>Subitem4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="itemc">Item 4
        <ul class="subitem">
            <li>Subitem1</li>
            <li>Subitem2</li>
            <li>Subitem3</li>
            <li>Subitem4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The whole script can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/74Jmr/2/)

My problem is when I press an item from the main list, the sub-list is shown, but the other items from the main list go one over the other. How or what should I modify to make it work? I mean, when an item is clicked the sublist to be shown and the next item to be aligned to the end of the sublist?

Comment: 1. Don't use the website's name as a nick. 2. Your problem is more to do with CSS than with JS.

Comment: @BackinaFlash could you be more specific about second point ?

Comment: @Back, there's no explicit reason to not use the site's name as a user-name, is there? Especially it's spelled wrong if that was the intent.

Comment: Thank you for your answers to my question!

Comment: @Stack Overfolow I don't see any answers. Do you? :)

Comment: @Morpheus it was a sarcastic comment to all the comments above ...

Comment: @Stack Overfolow Got ya :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two additional properties to your `.left  li` class:

```
.left  li {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74Jmr/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that when the subitem opens, the items positions aren't changed. They stay at the same place.

[image: 3D view from Firefox]

As you can see here (3D view from Firefox), items 3 and 4 still have their original place (item 2 clicked), and the subitem comes above them.

The subitem is actually not considered as being in the item. So when it's being displayed, the other items don't see any change in the item above them and stay at the same place. But the text is affected by the submenu though. And so it gets put at the end of it. All of this is due to the `float: left;` on the subitem.

To fix that, you just need to add `clear: both;` or `clear: left;` to `.left li` in the CSS.

*EDIT: Seems I am late sorry...*

Little note: You should avoid having `.left li` after `.left .submenu li`, it could replace some of the properties you put before.